# JSON_PARSING_ERROR: Unexpected character (r) at position 0

Tags: python, python-requests, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've been trying for a couple of days to send a notification via FCM using the Python requests package. But I've been struggling with the same issue over and over and I can't figure out what's wrong with my code.

Here's the JSON that I'm trying to send to Firebase:

```
{"registration_ids":["A token given by Firebase"],"notification": {"title":"1","body":"I'm a test message"}
```

I might have missed something, but as far as I know, the JSON message is well formatted. I've tried with both notification and message, but to no avail.

Here's the full code I'm using to do this:

```
import requests

URL = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'
data = {"registration_ids":["A token from Firebase"],"notification": {"title":"1","body":"I'm a test message"}}
headers = {"Authorization":"key=My server key","Content-Type":"application/json"}

print(data)
r = requests.post(url=URL, data=data, headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

It should return a message with a correct status but instead it's returning a 400 OK, JSON_PARSING_ERROR: Unexpected character (r) at position 0.

I'm not completely sure if I'm doing anything wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you have tried `print(r.json)`?

Comment: Yes, it returns: <bound method Response.json of <Response [400]>>

Comment: If I don't put the 'key=', it returns that the request was missing an Authentication Key (FCM Token)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to send `data` as JSON, you need to actually produce that JSON:

```
import json
data=json.dumps(data)
requests.post(<...>,data=data)
```

or use `post()`'s [`json`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.post) argument:

```
requests.post(<...>,json=data)
```